# I have header fixed with 500px height. I want to scroll page when click on menu link but its going below header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I want to scroll to section when click on menu link. I used "id" for each section.
Page is scrolling but its showing next section or going to the end of page of which id is clicked. I am using bootstrap and I increased my header size nearly 300px and it is fixed at top.

Comment: Could you provide some code you have wrote so far? You can use http://jsfiddle.net for easy code sharing.

Comment: If you are using internal links but on scroll it doesn't go to the correct link, you probably have misplaced margin or padding space. Please create a demo to replicate the problem.